# How to create a custom progress bar on msi using wix3?

Tags: custom-action, wix3.5, wix3

I am Building an MSI Installer using Wix 3, I need a progressbar to show to the user the progress of a custom action that is being executed, I've created the Dialog with the progressbar but how to 'link' the progressbar to my custom action? My custom action is in C++, I already tried using WcaProgressMessage but the progress still empty.